# Pure CSS Locked Table Headers - Variable Width and Height with Veritcal and Horizontal Scroll Bars

Tags: css, html

Is there a Pure CSS approach that locks headers in a `thead` element while having the entire table be a variable width and for the table content to be scrollable both vertically and horizontally?

I found this solution, but the columns are fixed width, and the table is fixed width, and there are no horizontal scroll bars:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

I found this solution, which is **almost** perfect, except that you can't scroll the table content horizontally:

http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Are there any solutions that use only CSS to have a single table scrollable vertically and horizontally and do not require the columns and table to be a fixed width?

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the code in the examples you provided? A slight modification to the second example would suit your needs. It's not entirely a table, the "thead" is actually a div made to look like one, and the rest of the table is wrapped inside another div with an overflow. You can set the size of this div, then have the table as big as you want. Just set the overflows accordingly.